# Mostrar archivo local txt en una listView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, listview, arrayadapter

Estoy haciendo una aplicación `android` y quisiera guardar los datos de un archivo `.txt` local, que utilizo como base de datos, en una `ArrayList <String>` y luego mostrarlos en la `ListView` que tengo. El caso es que he creado un método que crea la `ArrayList` con los datos que quiero mostrar pero no me lee bien el archivo `.txt` o ni siquiera ejecuta el método. Os dejo el código:

```
public class ActivityDatos extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

String NOMBRE_ARCHIVO = "prueba.txt";
ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos);

    try {
        añadirDatos3();
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Este metodo crea una string cada 3 lineas y lo añade a la arraylist info
void añadirDatos() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileIS = openFileInput(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fileIS);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String text, aux = "";
    int tipus = 0;

    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (tipus == 0) {
            aux = text + ", total: ";
            tipus = 1;
        } else if (tipus == 1) {
            aux = aux + text + "  (";
            tipus = 2;
        } else {
            aux = aux + text + ")";
            info.add(aux);
            aux = "";
            tipus = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hola Ferran , ¿ cual es la estructura de tu archivo podrías agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: Si, la estructura seria: Nombre - Entero - Fecha, donde el - representa un salto de linea, un ejemplo:
Ferran
23
01/01/2019
Jose
9
02/03/2019